# Compile F# source at runtime with Codedom?

Tags: f#, .net-assembly

I need to compile some f# source files at run-time into an assembly.

At the moment I am using [Fsharp.Compiler.CodeDom](https://github.com/fsprojects/powerpack) and it does what I need it to do, however it seems like this library hasn't been maintained. 
I would like to know, am I using the right one?

Note: I saw some answers to similar questions to this one, but the questions were a few years old.

Comment: I believe fsharp compiler services allows this - see http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/compiler.html

Comment: yes, that works, want to put it as an answer? There was some tweaking regarding the Fsharp.core but it's ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should actually go to John Palmer.... the spinet from his link basically just works

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv

    let scs = SimpleSourceCodeServices();
    let fn = Path.GetTempFileName();
    let fn2 = Path.ChangeExtension(fn, ".fs");
    let fn3 = Path.ChangeExtension(fn, ".dll");

    File.WriteAllText(fn2, """ 
module File1
  let seven =
           3 + 4
        """);

    let errors1, exitCode1 = scs.Compile([| "fsc.exe"; "-o"; fn3; "-a"; fn2 |])
    let ex = File.Exists(fn3)
    printfn "File %s exists: %b" fn3 ex
```

I have to admit it would be cool to see a non fsc.exe option :D